# WebAPI debugging - Start Chrome Postman from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am developing a Web API in Visual Studio 2015 and want to use Chrome/Postman to view the JSon results.

Is there any way I can get Postman to launch when I hit F5 to run and for Visual Studio to start a debugging session.

Comment: I don't think so, and you don't need this in fact. Just start your API in debug mode, and let a Postman tab/app opened. If you have a breakpoint set in your code, when you send a request from Postman, it you hit that breakpoint and you can start debugging. There's also no way VS can know if Postman is ever installed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can!

You have to configure the Web tab of the Web API project to start an external program, pointing it to Chrome and passing in the parameters to tell Chrome to launch the Postman extension.

In Chrome:

1. Go to chrome://apps/
2. Right-click Postman shortcut and create a desktop icon
3. Right-click Postman shortcut and view the properties, you'll find the path and parameters.
   [image: Postman extension launch parameters]

In Visual Studio, configure the web tab of the project properties:
[image: Visual Studio project properties]

Now, when you hit F5... Postman will automatically launch.

Comment: Yeah..... Postman launches...... but sadly, Visual Studio then ends the debugging session....

Comment: Well, that's no good! I have multiple projects in my solution and am configured to run several of them at debug time (it's got a client calling the web API).  Maybe because of that, debugging is long lived for me.

Comment: Had the same issue where Postman will launch but then the debugging session ends with error "The program '[17648] chrome.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to add Postman to the "Browse With" menu:

[image]

Selecting **Add** in the window that shows up after clicking on **Browse With...** will open a new form where you're asked to enter the path to the Chrome executable and the cmd line arguments for starting Postman. (See Mike L.'s post for details on getting those)

After that you can select Postman (or whatever friendly name you gave it) in the dropdown and F5 will launch Postman and start your debugging session.